# Click Event tracking setup

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, element, analytics, tracking

I am trying to count the clicks of certain elements on a web page using Google Analytics, which Im new to.  I set it up yesterday and here is the code I have:

Placed before the closing `</head>` tag (per instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking)), I have this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-33903909-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
        </script>
        </head>
```

I also have a set of elements:

```
                    <div class="block aside" id ="slideAside">
                    <aside>
                        <form class="form">
                            <fieldset id="fs_section_abstract" class="fs section abstract">
                                <label id="fs_abstract_heading" class="fs btn heading abstract">Abstract</label>
                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset id="fs_section_businessapproach" class="fs section businessapproach">
                                <label id="fs_businessapproach_heading" class="fs btn heading businessapproach">Business Approach</label>
                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset id="fs_section_workexperience" class="fs section workexperience">
                                <label id="fs_workexperience_heading" class="fs btn heading workexperience">Work Experience</label><br>
                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset id="fs_section_academic" class="fs section academic">
                                <label id="fs_academic_heading" class="fs btn heading academic">Academic</label>
                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset id="fs_section_skillstable" class="fs section skillstable">
                                <label id="fs_skillstable_heading" class="fs btn heading skillstable">Skills Table</label><br>
                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset id="fs_section_community" class="fs section community">
                                <label id="fs_community_heading" class="fs btn heading community">Community</label><br>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </aside>
                </div>
```

and to track them, in the script below, I have:

```
    $('.btn').click(function () {
    //FS IDentifier
    if ($(this).hasClass("fs")) {
        //heading
        if ($(this).hasClass("heading")) {
            //track number of times clicked
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Heading', 'The ID is' + $(this).attr('id') + '.']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Heading', 'HEading']);
```

I have had GA Analytics set up for almost a day now, and tried the above two `_gaq.push()`es as well as several other methods, but nothing is registering on the 'Events' section of the 'Content' section in the analytics page.

Am I misunderstanding something?   Is my code bad?

I know this is asynchronous tracking, but are the results updated daily or some other interval?  If it is daily, do you have to pay for synchronized updating?

Comment: I think answers to `are the results updated daily or some other interval? If it is daily, do you have to pay for synchronized updating?` would be best answered by Google Analytics documentation

Comment: Do you have a link to that information, as I have searched, and read all of the documentation that I thought relevant, and still did not find that information.   Given that realtime user page visits is occurring, I thought at least the account link was working, but am unsure of the time delay if any of asynchronous.

Comment: [What’s happening on your site right now?](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/09/whats-happening-on-your-site-right-now.html)  Basically, you have to be running the newest version of Google Analytics (not sure if it's still Beta, you may have to opt-in or change your settings or something).

Comment: Code looks good, may just not have shown up in GA yet, takes more than 24 hours. Just to check, is your GA tracking code ABOVE the script that performs `_gaq.push`?

Comment: @MrOBrian I have the latest version(which includes the Real time functionality, which is beta).  the 'Active visitors on site' works, but the content section under the Real time setting and under the 'Standard Reporting' it does not, so I am thinking its the way I have written my code.  I have also tried identify it by the `id` with this `   $('#fs_abstract_heading').click(function () {_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Heading', 'The ID is' + $(this).attr('id')]); alert("You have tracked a click with Google Analytics"); });` and I get the alert, so I know I am clicking it, just not sure about code

Comment: @Fresheyeball Love the name(+1) Does it take more than 24 hours for each thing it is tracking always?, or just a 24 hour delay from initial setup?  Sorry for the seemingly silly question, just new to this and CP in general.  Assuming `your GA tracking code` is the first code posted in the question, then yes.  In the page script at the bottom is where I call `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Heading', 'l2r - The ID is' + $(this).attr('id')])`.  I read that you can split this code into two, as long as the first part four lines are together, finished by the final `</script>, but I havent got that far.

Comment: @chrisFrisina 24 hours to track each event. Yeah just wanted to make sure _gaq got declared before you started using it.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Post in answer, and tomorrow when I see ill give credit.  Such a simple thing that I could not find an answer to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download Chrome if you don't already have it and install the [Google Analytics Debugger extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna).

Make sure your jquery click function is properly coded. Your code snippet is not valid.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJEJ6/) in Chrome and turn on the debugger. I ran it with the debugger on and the events were tracked.

Event tracking has appeared for me within 3 - 6 hours. Google always says to wait 24 hours for accurate tracking. But, to check the tracking immediately, download Chrome and the GA debugger.

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you referring to the absence of the closing  `} } });`​? if so, I'm good, if not, please point out the difference.   I looked at the tool, and Thanks a lot, great hint/help.  Now I have to wait on Google.

Comment: Great answer. Just wanted to add that you don't really need the GA Debugger extension, just the Chrome Developer Console (have a look at the GIF images' URLs).